# Trying to replace text to a span inside of a hyperlink

Tags: jquery

This is the code I'm using with no results

```
 $("#zodiacSymbol").text("testing");

<a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">My Web <span id="zodiacSymbol">zzz</span></a>
```

Comment: What errors do you see in the console? Did you include jQuery? What you have works for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fnavnb6n/

Comment: If the script is above the HTML, as in the example, then you're setting the text of an element that doesn't exist.  Move the JS to below the element.

Comment: i guess you omit the add jquery into your html

Comment: Matthew Johnson Thank you your answer was the correct one.